# Maximum number of captures in a position

Tags: problems, records, captures

I was wondering what the maximum number of captures in a position is, either in a real game or a problem.

Comment: You need to flesh this out a little more before it'll be answerable. Do you mean the maximum number of different possible moves which are captures, available to a single player in a given position? Both players? Maximum number of consecutive captures from both sides, starting from a given position?

Comment: Does the position have to be legal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have some records from a book published in 1969. They might have been surpassed since then, but if that is the case, I was not able to locate that information. I guess, since there is no reply after ~2 weeks, this should be better than nothing. These are records for captures by one side.

**74 captures; legal position:**

```
[Title "T. W. Marlow & William Cross, Problem 05/1967"]
[FEN "r1n1n1b1/1P1P1P1P/1N1N1N2/2RnQrRq/2pKp3/3BNQbQ/k7/4Bq2 w - - 0 1"]
```

Additional Source: [Die Schwable Chess Problem Database Server](https://pdb.dieschwalbe.de/P1178639)

**Edit: In response to the comment - here's a legal position without underpromotions in play, 65 captures possible.**

```
[Title "T. W. Marlow & William Cross, Problem 05/1967"]
[FEN "k2Kb2R/1RrQnQN1/8/BqQbQqQn/8/1QbQqQNB/8/3rQq2 w - - 0 1"]
```

Additional Source: [Die Schwable Chess Problem Database Server](https://pdb.dieschwalbe.de/P1178637)

Source: *Guide To Fairy Chess* by Anthony Dickins.

Comment: Very good. Of course it's only 53 without the underpromotions. One could argue that bxa8Q, bxa8R, bxa8B, bxa8N should not count as four different captures, because promotion takes place **after** the capture.

Comment: @bof True. Added another diagram from the same book where underpromotions are not in play.