# Maximum number of quiet moves in a position

Tags: problems, pawn-promotion, records, captures

The question of how many captures a position can have has been asked in the past: [Maximum number of captures in a position](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/8323/maximum-number-of-captures-in-a-position)

Without captures, and without promotion, which I define as “quiet” moves, what is the maximum number of quiet moves that one side can have in a legal chess position can have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum number for one side in a legal position is **216 quiet moves**, according to [this](https://pdb.dieschwalbe.de/P1179374) 46 year old chess problem.

```
[Title "Thur Row, Chess Ultimates 1974, 216 Non-Capturing Moves"]
[FEN "R6R/1K3Q2/3Q4/1Q4Q1/4Q3/2Q4Q/Q4QNN/2BB3k w - - 0 1"]
```